# Speed up time to fix GPS - C# Windows

Tags: c#, gps

I develop an application (C# Windows) and I need to get quickly the current position of the device.

There is a GPS (port COM) on my x86 device and a cellular modem (with a SIM card).
The GPS fix is got in 5~8 minutes, sometimes more...

**How speed up it ?**

Edit:
A Smartphone can quickly displayed an aproximated position on a map, how does it work? May be I can do the same thing with my SIM card ?

Comment: I'd think the answer will depend a lot on what cellular modem it is, and whether there are APIs for it.

Comment: Can you post which device you are using?  Sounds like it is doing a cold-boot every time, in which case 5-8 minutes is normal.

Comment: @Brad it is a "cinterion" modem, and I use AT commands (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) to make calls, etc..

Comment: Yes, [nearly] all modems these days use AT commands, but I am asking about the GPS side.  Also, Cinterion makes about 100 different products.  Can't you provide the model number or something more to go off of?  Better yet, look up a command reference for us so we don't have to do it for you.  Then, we can suggest what might be of use to you, and how to use it.

Comment: @brad I have not seen any commands in the spec about get latitude-longitude.  I've edited the question.

Comment: @scrat789, how do you expect us to help you if you cannot provide a model number at least?  There are often commands that you can give to the GPS, a last-known position and almanac, to speed up time-to-fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time to fix the position depends mainly in the chipset and technology in use in the device.

I remember that I needed to wait up to 10 minutes (SIRF 2) for a complete fix with TomTom, but now days all devices use [SIRF 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SiRFstar_III) and more than 20 channels to get the satellites position which is a lot faster, plus there are chipsets that use [WAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System)/[EGNOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Geostationary_Navigation_Overlay_Service) for enhance position accuracy.

Mobile devices tend to use a faster type which is called [AGPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS), where it gets from cellular towers (and Wi-Fi if available) the area and it's much faster to find the correct satellites from an area rather than query all to see where the device is (what WAAS/EGNOS do, but much faster).

Just try to check what chipset your device is using, and you will see if those 8 minutes are "normal" or not.

I had a QTek 2020 (Windows Mobile) and bought a [GlobalSAT BT-3xx](http://www.globalsat.com.tw/products-page.php?menu=2&gs_en_product_id=2&gs_en_product_cnt_id=25) (was the 388 but from 8 years ago) and TomTom took around 2 minutes to fix-it, where if I used the SIRF2 GPS module I had, took those 10 minutes!

Comment: I'm guessing that was from someone that has no clue how GPS system work